# emailing dynamically created fields PHP + JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can't find an exact answer to this and I am not a developer myself so its probably something simple which I am doing wrong.

I have created a form which can dynamically add a group of fields using jquery and cloning a  tag as follows:

```
<div class="container"><li id="li_6" >
    <label class="description" for="element_6">Advert Title (Up to 35 characters including spaces) </label>

        <input id="element_6" name="element_6[]" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 

    </li>       <li id="li_7" >
    <label class="description" for="element_7">Advert Body Text (Up to 70 characters including spaces) </label>

        <textarea id="element_7[]" name="element_7" class="element textarea small"></textarea> 

    </li>       <li id="li_8" >
    <label class="description" for="element_8">Advert Keywords (These are the words or phrases your potential customers will search for. Only 1 per line) </label>

        <textarea id="element_8[]" name="element_8" class="element textarea medium"></textarea>
```

```
    <a href="#" id="add">
Click to Add Another Advert</a> <a href="#" id="remove">| Remove Last Advert</a>
</li>
```

All of this works fine, the only problem is that when email function is run, I only get the latest added group of fields and not all of them on the received email:

```
if($act=="post"){
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: 123Click<support@123click.co.za>' . "\r\n";
$to       = 'support@123click.co.za';
$subject  ='New Adwords Setup';
$message  = "<b><u>Section A: Login</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message  = "<b>Login Email:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_1"].'<br>';
$message  = "<b><u>Section B: Settings</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Location:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_9"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Daily Budget:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_10"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Web Address:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_4"].'<br>';
$message  = "<b><u>Section C: Adverts</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Title:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_6"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Body:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_7"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Keywords:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_8"].'<br>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

What am I doing wrong, and please explain as simply as possible. Thanks

Comment: See what happens when you run var_dump($_POST);

Comment: You post either array or value... name="element_6[]" VS name="element_7"

Comment: <input id="element_6" name="element_6[]" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>

Comment: Also, you're overwriting `$message` twice.

Answer (score 0):

first of all be careful with the "$message  =" it should be

```
$message  = "<b><u>Section A: Login</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Login Email:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_1"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b><u>Section B: Settings</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Location:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_9"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Daily Budget:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_10"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Web Address:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_4"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b><u>Section C: Adverts</u></b>&nbsp;".'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Title:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_6"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Body:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_7"].'<br>';
$message .= "<b>Advert Keywords:</b>&nbsp;".$_POST["element_8"].'<br>';
```

then i think you should make an " for each " name on form